# hide clicked input on ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a button added by third part module. When click on this button, the third module sends an ajax request (I can't change the third party code). How can I hide this button on `ajaxStart` and show it on `ajaxStop`?

I tried:

```
$('#buttonId').click(function() {
    $(this).ajaxStart(function() { $(this).hide(); }).ajaxStop(function() { $(this).show(); });
});
```

But it doesn't work right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found simple solution, thanks for help:

```
var tmp = false;

$('.button').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    tmp = $(this);
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    if (tmp) {
         tmp.show();
         tmp = false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4YJyk/2/

```
$('#buttonId').click(function() {
    $(this).ajaxStart(function() { $("#buttonId").hide(); }).ajaxStop(function() { $("#buttonId").show(); });
});
```

Edited

Comment: I don't have access to the third party html and javascript. Maybe try added this span dinamic?

Comment: I think the final problem is how to add ajaxStart for dynamic added element?

Comment: Is the ajaxStart function being called?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the usage of this for anonymous function in that function `this` related to function not the click event so you can use this approach,

```
$('#buttonId').click(function() {
    var button = $(this);
    button.ajaxStart(function() { button.hide(); }).ajaxStop(function() { button.show(); });
});
```

EDIT: 
After your comment I check the `ajaxStart` I thought it is some plugin of yours but it s a global event so you cannot attach that guy to a button you can only attach it to document and when a AJAX request starts or ends the related event triggered. Please see here.
http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/ When you attach that event to a object you can access it with this but it never cause the trigger the event. So you can do something like this.

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
  $( "#buttonId" ).hide();
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
  $( "#buttonId" ).show();
});
```

To trigger this event you have to make an AJAX request like;

```
$( "#buttonId" ).click(function () { $("#divId").load("DivContent.aspx") });
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks of help, but I tried and your version - not work too :(

Comment: @IgorLadela can you please check my edited answer and inform me if it helps. Cheers.